# Set Custom Form Element Value in Extended LinkWidget Class

Tags: 8, forms, plugins

I have a class extending LinkWidget and would like to add a new form element.

*I have omitted all code except what I have added*:

```
class CustomWidget extends LinkWidget {

  public static function defaultSettings() {
    return [
      'placeholder_field_name' => '',
    ] + parent::defaultSettings();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $element['field_name'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this
        ->t('field name'),
      '#placeholder' => $this
        ->getSetting('placeholder_field_name'),
      '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]->field_name) ? $items[$delta]->field_name : '',
      '#maxlength' => 255,
    ];

    return $element;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function settingsForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $elements = parent::settingsForm($form, $form_state);
    $elements['placeholder_field_name'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this
        ->t('Placeholder for field name'),
      '#default_value' => $this
        ->getSetting('placeholder_field_name'),
    ];
    return $elements;
  }

   /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function settingsSummary() {
    $summary = [];
    $placeholder_field_name = $this
      ->getSetting('placeholder_field_name');
    if (empty($placeholder_field_name)) {
      $summary[] = $this
        ->t('No placeholders');
    }
    else {
      if (!empty($placeholder_field_name)) {
        $summary[] = $this
          ->t('field name placeholder: @placeholder_field_name', [
          '@placeholder_field_name' => $placeholder_field_name,
        ]);
      }
    }
    return $summary;
  }

}
```

The form element exists but is not being set, so I cannot save and access any values from the `textfield`. Maybe more accurate, the form element does not appear in `kpr($items[$delta])`.

Can I get this form element to set its value to the form settings?

Comment: Where do you want to add a new form element, to the widget or the settings form? Can you post the code?

Comment: I've updated my question with some code. This would be for the node add/edit form.

Comment: I'm still not sure whether this is about setting or widget. Since the setting only sets a placeholder it seems not critical, so you could reduce the code to formElement() to reproduce the problem without a placeholder. But then there is  the last line in your question having the question mark at the end. So are these two separate questions?

Comment: I could have my terminology mixed up, I would say the issue is I can add a textfield to the form, but nothing gets saved when I save the form. It seems the custom form element isn’t registered.

Comment: Then I assume the problem is only in formElement(). Perhaps you can try to reduce the problem to this method and remove all placeholder stuff. What seems odd is the naming of the element. `field_name` should be a property of the field type, not a node field as the name suggests.